# Not Able to Properly Set Relative URLs

Tags: html, image, url

The root folder of the project is Wildcat. In Wildcat, there's two folders.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Wildcat\Images

C:\xampp\htdocs\Wildcat\Users
```

I want to display a picture that's in Images on a document that's in Users. I've tried:

```
<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\Wildcat\Images\test.jpeg">
```

and

```
<img src=Wildcat\Images\test.jpeg>
```

(I've also tried turning the slashes into regular backslashes; no different was made.)

I've looked for solutions beforehand, but I think that I'm having difficulties wording my problem, as all of the solutions I've found haven't helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can "go up" a directory with ../

If I understand your HTML is found within "Users" so it would be like:

```
<img src="../Images/test.jpeg">
```